# Bootstrap Slider - How to prevent the crossing/flipping of handle controls on the slide

Tags: jquery, event-handling, rangeslider, bootstrap-slider

I need to apply a limit for both slider-handles in the slider range control of bootstrap-slider, i.e. do not cross each other... like the jquery slider UI that the both handles stops the slide control behavior, and never cross.

I try to do with setting Value and returning false, but doesn't works

```
        $(this).slider({
                formatter: function(slidervalue) {
                    return '$' + slidervalue;
                },
                min: parseFloat($(this).attr('data-slider-min')),
                max: parseFloat($(this).attr('data-slider-max')),
                range: $(this).attr('data-slider-range'),
                value: slidervalue,
                tooltip_split: $(this).attr('data-slider-tooltip_split'),
                tooltip: $(this).attr('data-slider-tooltip'),
                tooltip_position: 'bottom'
            });
            $(this).on("slide", function(slideEvt) {
                var rangeVal = $(this).val();
                var splitRange = rangeVal.split(',');
                var check0 = splitRange[0];
                var check1 = splitRange[1];
                 if (check0 == check1) {
                    $(this).slideStop();

                }
           });
```

Thank you for your help

Answer (score 0):

I made an update in my codepen example, and get it
I change the bgcolor of each handler to make it more visible

https://codepen.io/alonsoct00/pen/xojLdE

```
$(this).attr('data-slider-tooltip_split'),
```